# Geolocalizacion cordova y javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocalización

Me gustaria poder sacar el valor de la variable lat fuera de la funcion, para ponerlo en un form.
En este caso, solo queria sacar un alert (lat), pero no funciona.
O lo muestra todo o nada, pero solo lat no.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">



        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);


    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                                    'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />';


    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                           }

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
    <script>alert (lat);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Que es mostrar todo?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres obtener los valores de **latitude** y **longitud** en un formulario, hazlo asi :

En tu funcion **onSuccess**:

```
  function onSuccess(position) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("long").value = position.coords.longitude;
  }
```

Esto implica que en tu vista deberias tener algo asi:

```
<form action="#">
     Latitude:<br>
     <input type="text" id="lat" value="">
     Longitude:<br>
     <input type="text" id="long" value="">
</form>
```

Haciendo esto podras asignar los valores de Latitude y Longitud en tus campos de formulario.